# Хуки slimframework

Tags: php-frameworks, slim

Разбираюсь с slimframework. Создал тестовое приложение, файл index.php выглядит примерно так(лишнее не писал, все как в доках):

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
```

И есть два файла(класса) - Pages и Users, оба они наследуются от файла(класса) Frontend. Pages выглядит примерно так

```
    class Pages extends \Frontend
    {
      public function index($app)
      {
       $app->applyHook('pages.before.index');
        echo "hi from pages module";
       $app->applyHook('pages.after.index');
      }
    }
```

Файле Users:

```
class Users extends \Frontend
{
  public function __construct($app)
  {
    $app->hook('pages.before.index', function () use($app) {
        echo 'hi from users';
    });
  }
}
```

Как вы понимаете при обращении к методу index класса Pages должно вывести следующее

hi from users

hi from pages module

Но выводится только "hi from pages module" Если явно создать объект в файле index.php

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$users = new \Users($app);
```

То все работает. Есть идея хранить где-то все названия классов, и в цикле создавать их(т.е. как показано выше new \Users($app) и т.д.), но что-то мне подсказывает что это очень плохая идея, и возможно кто-то из вас сможет подсказать более правильное решение.